# Schemas, Migrations, and schemaVersion when models are split between modules?

Tags: react-native, realm

Having trouble with some design decisions related to the fact that schemaVersion is realm-wide and not per-model. My goals:

- Modules can expose 'models', which are just objects that have:

  - name, label, other useful meta-data
  - 'schemas', an array of objects like: `{version: 1, schema: {...}, migration: (optional)}`
- An orchestrator module then provides the glue to load all these model modules, create the Realm object from them and run pending migrations (in a very similar manner to the example in your docs)

The problem: How to create a realm-wide schemaVersion that properly increments when any of the modules have new versions? Keep in mind you could stop using any given model module, so something like adding up all the version wouldn't work.

Comment: Some ideas I've played with: Tracking all the model versions in a 'system' realm, so the orchestrator knows which sub-migrations to run. This 'system' realm could even keep all the old schemas around (such that the modules don't have to keep them around, only the old migration functions.

Comment: Are you using Realm with React Native, or in some other environment?

Comment: @bdash Yes, realm with react-native.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use multiple Realms, one for each model or set of models which require their own schemaVersion. If you do this then you can specify a different migration block and schemaVersion for each model. You would need to use different Realm names for each realm but using the model name seems intuitive.

Comment: I would assume you can't have any nested relationships then. Could get around that in most cases with just lists of ids (though you can't just do list of strings afaik, so you'd make a model of some type.

Comment: Correct - I would recommend putting objects which link to each in the same Realm so they are all migrated together. Ids would work as well but requires an extra fetch for each object lookup.